# How can i automatically rename a tab with todays date

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to coding, just started. But I can't figure it out how to rename a tab in the script with the date of its creation.

This is all I have (not much)

spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);

I have a trigger for a google form, and I want to rename the tab with today's date from the answers of the form.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting the sheetnames to todays date

```
function onMyOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dts = Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMddyyyy")
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh,i) => sh.setName(`${dts}-${i + 1}`));
}
```

- Create an installable onOpen trigger because the script requires the following scope:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: Thanks, it’s working, but it’s changing all the tab names, just need to change the name of a new tab that's created with a script. It changes every time a new response is submitted, "Sheetxx" //xx being the number . 

Sorry if its confusing, I’m new to this.

Comment: All you need to do is get the Sheet object and use the setName() method along with the Utilities.formatDate()